# Accessing User Application Settings in a WPF Prism 4 module

Tags: wpf, configuration, prism

I have developed a Microsoft Prism 4.0 application and I am struggling to understand how to make the user application setting functionality available to modules.

e.g. a Properties.Settings.Default.MyProperty.

I can define a simple class that gets populated via the bootloader (which does have a handle to the properties) and inject that into the modules but If I want to save a change of property, I need believe I need a handle to the Properties.Settings context which is not available to my modules (which are simple class libraries).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your scenario sounds like the perfect reason to use a "Service" class.  Create an interface and class called IUserSettingsService and UserSettingsService that has the information (or can load and save it from where it is stored).

Read Chapter 3 of the Prism 4.0 help file, Managing Dependencies Between Components, Registering Types with (either Unity or MEF, depending on what you are using as your DI Container).

Then, in your ViewModel that needs the user settings, locate and use your service.  In MEF, it is as simple as adding a property of type IUserSettingsService with an [Import] attribute, or using [ImportingConstructor] and having a parameter of type IUserSettingsService.  With Unity, you access the service through the container.  See Chapter 10 of the Prism help file - Advanced MVVM Scenarios.

Added after comment discussion:
Because you need your service to be in the context of your main application, you can implement your service class there.  Create the interface for your service in a shared library that can be used by both the main project and your modules.  Finally, load the service in the bootloader class instead of in a module.

Comment: Bahri. Thanks for your response.Your answer is not quite what I need. I already have a service that I copy the Properties.Settings I require and inject into my modules via the IModule.Initialize (I create a new constructor to do this)). The issue is more around getting a handle to the Properties.Settings context which is only available to the main application project. It does not seem very clean to create a wrapper service in this project and then have the modules I require, reference main application project. In fact I suspect I cannot do this as it would create a circular reference.

Comment: @Jemmitch I think I see your dilemma.  Your service implementation needs to be in your main application project in order to access the Properties.Settings, but your interface should be defined in an assembly referenced by both your main application project as well as the modules.  This way the service can be injected without having any circular dependencies.  Have I got that right?

Comment: You have grasped the issue. The implementation needs to sit in the main application. The interface as you say could be in a shared assembly but at some point the module needs to know about the concrete implementation when configuring DI for for the module.

Comment: How about putting the interface in that other library (I use an assembly called Framework for that type of stuff), having the service class in the main application project, and registering your service with the DI in your shell?  Am I missing something else?

Comment: So far my experience of registering dependencies for Unity based DI has this all happening in the module (where my viewmodels are that would make use of this service). I have not seen any examples where modules in projects separate to the shell make use of DI from the shell.

Comment: You can register services from anywhere if I am not mistaken (I use MEF, not Unity, so all I have to do is [Export] a service).  I suggest adding a registration to your Bootloader for this service, although anywhere after the DI is initialized should be fine.

Comment: I hear what your saying. It is lste here (Uk) so will try this first thing tomo. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Registering the service in the bootloader rather than the module intialize is the answer. This now works for me. I am accepting your answer but it could probably do with an edit to reflect your more informed answer. Thanks for everything.